# golang - Send bytes to tcp connection, without response nor error

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

When I try to send a byte array(size 1024Byte=1004 + 20 header lenth) to a tcp connection,
it should return size of bytes sent or a error, but there's nothing return.
The program run into fd.Write then nothing happed.

codes

```
func xxx {
    ...
    log.Debugf("Try to send data to connection remote %s, local %s",
        cm.connMap[cm.transferConnKey].conn.RemoteAddr().String(),
        cm.connMap[cm.transferConnKey].conn.LocalAddr().String())
    n, err := cm.connMap[cm.transferConnKey].conn.Write(pktBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return err
    }
    log.Debugf("Send %d bytes data to %s", n, cm.connMap[cm.transferConnKey].conn.RemoteAddr().String())
    return nil
}
```

tcp connection

```
➜  ~ ss -anp | grep 52722
tcp   ESTAB      0      4052096                                                           127.0.0.1:52722                127.0.0.1:7023  users:(("narwhal",pid=6935,fd=3))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
tcp   ESTAB      77178  0                                                        [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:7023        [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:52722 users:(("narwhal",pid=6714,fd=10))
```

log

```
INFO[2022-06-08 20:13:34]/home/shawn/Workspaces/narwhal/service/handles.go:141 narwhal/service.handleReply() Registry client succeed                      

DEBU[2022-06-08 20:13:41]/home/shawn/Workspaces/narwhal/service/handles.go:174 narwhal/service.handleDataClient() New connection local address 127.0.0.1:57242 remote address 127.0.0.1:22 
DEBU[2022-06-08 20:13:41]/home/shawn/Workspaces/narwhal/service/handles.go:193 narwhal/service.handleDataClient() Send 1004 bytes data to 127.0.0.1:22         
DEBU[2022-06-08 20:13:41]/home/shawn/Workspaces/narwhal/service/handles.go:333 narwhal/service.forwardToNW() Read 1004 bytes data from 127.0.0.1:22       
DEBU[2022-06-08 20:13:41]/home/shawn/Workspaces/narwhal/service/handles.go:347 narwhal/service.forwardToNW() Try to send data to connection remote 127.0.0.1:7023, local 127.0.0.1:52722 
^C
```

It print log try to send data...
but conn.Conn.Write([]byte) without any response
and the tcp connection is ESTABLISHED
So, what going on, why it doesn't return anything

full code link:
https://github.com/lucheng0127/narwhal/blob/a4cffc76ee5ffb8d0e6f35598bb669c64cd0a9d4/service/handles.go#L350

Comment: are the data read from the other side of the connection ?

Comment: are you sure the data has the expected size ?

Comment: I read fix size 1004 bytes from connection, then I gonna add a 20 bytes header into it, so size of my pktBytes is 1024